# Change puTTy presets via registry

Tags: ssh, shell, windows-registry, putty

I am fixing presets through the `.reg` file instead of in puTTy because I am going to make this an open source registry. Mostly changing themes, and my school doesn't know what the hell they are doing and most of us would rather have the right click (context menu) option available to us. Here is a quick example of what I am editing::

```
"AlwaysOnTop"=dword:00000000
"FullScreenOnAltEnter"=dword:00000001
"HideMousePtr"=dword:00000001
"SunkenEdge"=dword:00000001
"WindowBorder"=dword:00000001
"CurType"=dword:00000000
"BlinkCur"=dword:00000001
```

Which I am guessing `dword` accepts binary. Can someone tell me where in these options is the right click override? Or if there is documentation for dummys basically of what each of these properties mean give me the link so I can read it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get a `.reg` file with your desired settings is to first **set them through PuTTY** – which conveniently has all the options described – then save into a session, and **export *that*** from Registry Editor. (You can even run a diff between the exported default session and custom session, to see what exactly changed.)

The setting you're looking for is in the `MouseIsXterm` value. It accepts the following data:

- 0 for "compromise" mode
- 1 for "Xterm" mode
- 2 for "Windows" mode

The last of which is written as `"MouseIsXterm"=dword:00000002`. Which is not binary; it's hexadecimal (`dword` or "double word" is 32 bits wide, which is written as 8 hex digits in .reg files).

Comment: Well thank you for clarifying this for me I appreciate it a lot! And I never thought to export from the regedit which I did originally for my template lol. And thanks on the double word explanation. What language is that?

Comment: @EasyBB: A "word" in computers usually means the typical [unit of data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) with which the CPU works. For example, x86 CPUs on PCs nowadays use 32-bit or even 64-bit words (though of course they have instructions dealing with smaller units like bytes as well). On PCs however, Windows 3.x started using this term when it meant 16 bits, and for compatibility reasons it still means the exact same amount even as x86 CPUs evolved. Thus a "double word" is 32 bits, and "quad word" is 64 bits.

Comment: @EasyBB: The `.reg` file format, meanwhile, isn't a language or really anything other than just "the .reg file format". It's just whatever the `regedit` developers have decided upon as a good format for exporting the values & data.

Comment: When looking inside regedit32 it states "Edit Binary Data" so Reg DWord is Binary data values.

Comment: @EasyBB: *Everything* in the registry is binary data. (Or, for that matter, in a computer.) Within the Windows registry, however, the REG_DWORD data type is usually _interpreted as_ a single 32-bit-wide integer, but of course stored as four 8-bit bytes.

Comment: ah ok yeah I was going to say. lol